# connection must be valid or open

Tags: vb.net, search, combobox

```
Private Sub View_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ''Search All data

    Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader
    Dim Query As String

    Try
        myConn.Open()


        Query = "SELECT*FROM datainfo"
        myComman = New MySqlCommand(Query, myConn)

        Reader = myComman.ExecuteReader

        While Reader.Read
            Dim sName = Reader.GetString("StudentName")
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(sName)
        End While

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    Finally
        myConn.Dispose()

    End Try
```

Comment: The error seems pretty clear.  The connection isn't open and valid when you try to use it.  It looks like you're using database objects from a larger scope, which is generally a bad thing.  This method should instantiate and own the database objects it internally uses, so nothing outside of its scope can modify the state of those objects.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: ohh..1 now i get it Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your declaring your data connection myConn isn't complete. 
There will be a lot of examples on how to do that with a quick Google search.
If you have the connection defined in a config file it will be be something like:

```
Dim myConn as New SqlConnection(configurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConn").ConnectionString)
```

On an unrelated note, you'll want to close the database connection and dispose of the command. So

```
Finally   
  myConn.close()
  myComman.dispose()
```

The garbage collector will automatically dispose of the command for you, but it doesn't hurt anything to do it yourself.